# How to put a users input into an array

Tags: python, arrays

I'm kinda new to python and i want to know how to put a users input into an array

for example:

```
usersentence = input("Type out the sentence: ")
```

I want to put what the user inputs into an array and i'm confused on how to do it. My program identifies what position the word is in the sentence and ignores punctuation and whether it is caps or not.

Thanks if you help!

Comment: you want to put the words of the question into an array?

Comment: `new_array.append(usersentence)` Show us your code, else we can't help you. All relevant parts of it.

Comment: show us how your input like

Comment: `usersentence=raw_input("Type out the sentence").split(' ')`

Comment: You need to be more precise. Let's say my input is `hi mom`. What do you want each element of the array to be in that case?

Comment: ...but also, please note we call them `list`s in Python :)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your item in a list like so :

```
usersentence = [input("Type out the sentence: ")]
print(usersentence)

>>> Type out the sentence: hello world
>>> ['hello world']
```

If you'd like one word per list item :

```
usersentence = input("Type out the sentence: ").split()
print(usersentence)

>>> Type out the sentence: hello world
>>> ['hello', 'world']
```